# Looking for an app to being able to save landmarks, locations, places, monuments, etc

Tags: ios, maps, geo-location, tracking

I’m looking for an app to save the landmarks, locations, places, coordinates, monuments, etc. that I’ve already visited and those I want to visit.

The OSs I use are iOS and MacOS. It is very important to have an iPhone app. On the computer I can use a web page if necessary.

Key features that would be nice to have:

- Folders: To be able to categorise the saved locations.
- Map: To be able to see the pins in a map.
- Location info: GPS coordinate, distance to the pin from my actual location, address, link to navigate with a 3rd party app.

Optional features that would be nice to have:

- No account needed: Sync through iCloud would be better that having to create an account.
- Tags: For being able to quickly find similar locations that are saved in distinct categories.
- Photos: For being able to see or add images of the place to quickly identify them.

Apps that I've already tried but haven't  worked for me:

- [Google Maps](https://www.google.es/maps): I know that Google Maps allow me to save places but I want to avoid using this service.
- [Mapstr](https://mapstr.com/): I've been using this app for a while but it becomes to social focus. In my case, I don't need to share or view other users list. I just want to store a lot of pins.
- [Anchor Pointer](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/anchor-pointer-gps-compass/id791684332): It is the one I'm using it right now but I miss two features. Being able to search by landmark name (you can only save coordinates) and being able to create folders/categories.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.openstreetmap.org its for mapping, with special focus for pedestrians or bikers, with a close interest in the surroundings!

Answer (score 0):

As a mapstr user myself, I don't care about the social features, but it is still the best app to store tons of pins. My profile being private, I don't share or look at other's lists.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. For now I'll avoid to returning to Mapstr. I hope to find an alternative. If I can't find it, then I suppose that I'll return to use it and deal with all the social stuff.